# Team System - Create a Sharepoint Project Portal for an existing team project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, tfs

I have an existing Team Project in Team System 2010 which, when I originally created it, I opted **not** to create a Sharepoint Project Portal website. I now would like a Sharepoint Project Portal website for the Team Project.

**How do I do this?**

In Visual Studio, I have tried Team->Team Project Settings->Portal Settings... and checking '"Enable team project portal" but I get the error:

> TF229003: No response was received from following SharePoint site:
>   htttp:/. Verify that it is operational, or specify another
>   site

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the TFS PowerTools have a command-line utility `tfpt` which lets you add a Project Portal for an existing Team Project.

```
tfpt addprojectportal
```

A blog post with a bit more info: http://www.doodle.co.uk/Blogs.aspx/2010/06/15/Rebuilding-TFS-Portals

Edit: another post with examples: http://ivanfioravanti.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/create-project-portal-and-reports-for-an-existing-team-project-on-tfs-2010/

Comment: Worth noting this won't *create* a project portal, but this powertool just lets you associate a project portal to an existing TeamProject.

Answer (score 0):

Install TFS PowerTools and in command line you can create the portal.

you have to close visual studio first.

here is the msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242865.aspx